# Using GraphQL for NLP models

Tags: sql, database, deep-learning, graphql, nlp

I have SQL Database. I want to create a NLP model that takes user Natural language query as input, process it to SQL query and fetch the required data from database.
My problem is, How do we use GraphQL here ?

As far as I researched, GraphQL is used to fetch the API data efficiently. But what is the purpose of using GraphQL here?
Or is there any other functionality of GraphQL that I missed!

Comment: no the graph in graphgl, means that you take your data and display it in a graph, but for more we would need more what data you want to get and how this should translate into a graph

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.